# Node,express,jade rendered pages doesn't data-bind with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, pug

I'm running a Node server with express which renders jade. I'm trying to make my client side use knockout.js but the view never updates... I don't get any errors in the console and I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Page:

```
extends layout

    block content

    script(src='knockout/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(src='js/app.js', type='text/javascript')

    p Hi,
        strong(data-bind="text: firstName")
```

rendered html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="knockout/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <p>Hi,<strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

is there something I'm missing here or is it just not possible to make this happen with Node.js and express?

Comment: Did you check the actual HTML output to make sure everything looks ok there?

Comment: I updated the post with the rendered html

Comment: +1 for question - i just wonder if Jade will work with Knockout.js and doesn't have to test it before i start my work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you call `ko.applyBindings()` after the DOM has already been loaded.

Either wrap the code in app.js in [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload), in jQuery's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, or move your script tag to be below `<p>Hi,<strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>`.

Answer (score -2):

// this is my js file
(function () {

```
//START THE APP WHEN DOCUMENT IS READY
$(function () {
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.firstName = "Hamza";
       // self.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

})();